# How to implement AsyncTask from the following example?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

I try to fix it but the list data doesn't show up..also, there is some red line in my code. `onPostExecute` it inform thatThe constructor `SimpleAdapter(EventsActivity.syncEvent, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, int, String[], int[])` is undefined.

Another thing, I would like to do is to show a `progress` when we refresh the even like when we refresh notification in facebook, we will see animation of refreshing the data, last date and time we did a refresh.How can i do that? Do you have any idea?  I am quite new to implementation. Thanks for your advice.

```
public class EventsActivity extends ListActivity {

    EventDataSet sitesList = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

    }

    private class syncEvent extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                /** Handling XML */
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
                URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                        "http://xxxx.heroku.com/xxxxxxxxxxx.xml");

                /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
                EventXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new EventXMLHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
            sitesList = EventXMLHandler.sitesList;

            /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
            for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("name", "Name: " + sitesList.getName().get(i));
                map.put("createat", "Create-At: " + Convertor.getDateTimeDDMMYY(sitesList.getCreateat().get(i)));

                mylist.add(map);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.eventitem,
                    new String[]{"name", "createat"},
                    new int[]{R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `this` reference. When you're inside the AsyncTask, `this` refers to your AsyncTask subclass, and SimpleAdapter requires a Context as the first parameter. You should replace the call with an explicit reference to the parent class:

```
new SimpleAdapter(EventsActivity.this, mylist , R.layout.eventitem, 
                new String[] { "name", "createat" }, 
                new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });
```

Answer (score 1):

now you can call it by this :: `new syncEvent().execute();`

like ::

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
    new syncEvent().execute();
}
```

Comment: probably one way.. to do, i have tried but it's not work i think the problem still occur coz i see the red underline in my code..at "onPostExecute" it inform that The constructor SimpleAdapter(EventsActivity.syncEvent, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, int, String[], int[]) is undefined